# Can't get WPF validator to fire when user adds new row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-4.0, validation

I have a WPF data grid with a custom validator to validate the entry of an E-Mail address. THe validation works when the user edits the text of a cell and my custom validation triggers as expected.

However, When the user adds a new row by clicking on the empty cell provided via the CanUserAddRows attribute, the validator doesn't' fire. In my code behind, I have a handler for my custom validator, which sets the a Save buttons'enabled state based on if there are any errors.

How can I get the validator to fire upon insertion of a new row?

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,1,2,-1" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailRecipients}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" Name="emailAddressBindingGrid">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                      Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email Address" Width="400" x:Name="emailAddressColumn" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellErrorStyle}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="ToAddress" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" x:Name="emailAddressBinding">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <Validators:EmailAddressValidator  ErrorMessage="A valid email address is required."  />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        // other columns
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

For a WinForms application you may have to handle the [DataGridView.RowValidating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx) when adding a new row.

Description from MSDN:

> This event is analogous to the Control.Validating event. Use this event to perform validation on all the values of a row. If the row does not pass validation, set the CancelEventArgs.Cancel property to true. Canceling this event prevents the RowValidated, Control.Validating, and Control.Validated events from occurring, and also prevents the user from leaving the invalid row and prevents the row from being saved to an external data source in data bound mode.

In `WPF` you might try to use the [DataGrid.RowValidationRules Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowvalidationrules(v=vs.110).aspx)

Description from MSDN:

> The DataGrid control enables you to perform validation at both the cell and row level. With cell-level validation, you validate individual properties of a bound data object when a user updates a value. With row-level validation, you validate entire data objects when a user commits changes to a row. To create a custom validation rule, create a class that derives from the ValidationRule class and implement the Validate method. Add the custom validation rule to the RowValidationRules collection.

Comment: Apart form the citation it's always good to include the link to the original site too where one can find more details. I've edited your answer.

Comment: DataGridView is WinForms. I am not sure what event this corresponds to in WPF DataGrid

Comment: The answer is edited an a possible solution for WPF has been added.